# Cryptic Ruby syntax for averaging ASCII values

Tags: ruby, syntax, ascii, average, gets

I saw an intriguing answer to a simple question.

The question was: "Get the average of the ASCII values of each character in a string read from `gets`"

One of the correct answer was: `p gets.sum/~/$/`

I searched Google but couldn't find any explanation for this syntax.  Any insights are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: This code looks very much like [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). While this is a great hobby and a good way to lean more about a language, you should make sure to not use those clever one-liners in actual production code. In real programs which are intended to be maintained for some time, aim for code which is boring, readable, and understandable instead of "clever".

Comment: @HolgerJust I would argue that those exact things make it a very poor way to learn more about a language.

Comment: @MarkThomas Well, it's not that you should use these one-liners exactly as you write them. But by trying to understand how they work (or even writing them yourself), you can gain a deep understanding about the syntactic and semantic details of a language. And this helps you later to detect and avoid potential issues in your production code you might not even notice without such a detailed understanding. You are absolutely right though in that code golf is usually not a great way to get a *basic* understanding of a language or to learn common and accepted idioms. It's still fun though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a couple things going on here

1. `gets.sum` is just calling [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sum) on the string input by `gets` and is returning an integer.

> The result is simply the sum of the binary value of each byte in str...

2. `/$/` is just a [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) looking for where the end of the line is
3. The [`~` operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-7E) on a [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) tells it to operate on the [`$_` global variable](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/globals_rdoc.html) which is the last string input to `gets` or `readline`. In short this returns the index of the end of the line

> Matches rxp against the contents of $_. Equivalent to rxp =~ $_.

4. Finally, tying these 2 together, we have a `/` which is just a division operator operating on 2 Integers.

It could have also been written using some spaces to make things more clear

```
p gets.sum / ~/$/
```

Note: If this was an average, they added in the value for `\n` but then didn't divide it back out:

```
gets.sum/~/$/
# Hello
# => 102
"Hello".sum / "Hello".length
# => 100
"Hello\n".sum / "Hello".length
# => 102
"Hello\n".sum / "Hello\n".length
# => 85
```